# Why does the United States have some of the best universities and tertiary education in the world yet only ranks average in K-12 education?

Tags: united-states, education

By universities, I would also include colleges of course. The claims about tertiary education and schools are generally well known, and backed by various [rankings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College_and_university_rankings).

In regards to K-12 education, there are a couple of studies done on that (wherein most find the same results). This [article](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2017/02/15/u-s-students-internationally-math-science/) from the Pew Research Center seems to be a good basis for the question.

Comment: The universities attract staff and students from all over the world. The schools are local.

Comment: @pjc50 the obvious follow up is how do they do that?

Comment: @pjc50 also, foreign students make up a small minority of all students in universities

Comment: Are you comparing select universities ("some of the best") vs overall primary and secondary?  How does secondary education in the U.S. compare if you take only the top 100-rated high schools?  What about tertiary education if you include all options (research university, teaching, college, community, religious, for-profit)?

Comment: You're also looking at a huge range of methodologies for University ranking vs surveys of parents/academics asked "Is it better, the same or worse than" for the K-12 ranks. (As far as I can see from the links anyway).

Comment: Gotta think the "excessive tuition fueled by huge spending increases fueled by the building booms fueled by competition for tuition dollars" cycle that has made college out of reach for so many, financially, is part of the reason so many more US universities rank high. I'd guess universities in nations where government foots the tuition bills directly probably aren't as free to charge whatever they feel like, and have to be more judicious about how they spend. That's speculative on my part, though.

Comment: @user4556274 My entirely-anecdotal-and-no-doubt-biased impression is that it’s actually below the top tier where US universities shine: many countries have stellar, top-tier schools (Oxford, Cambridge, and the Sorbonne come to mind), but the breadth, depth, and strength of second-tier, third-tier, etc. American universities is (it seems to me) unrivaled.

Comment: Better to compare prep schools to universities.  In the US public school is mandatory and universal, but universities are not.

Comment: @KRyan I disagree with your impression, and I don't think the breadth, depth, or strength of, say US state universities are any better than the equivalent in Canada, UK, France, Germany, Netherlands, Sweden. I'd go even further and claim that university rankings are poorly correlated with quality of education, since only the best-performing students get in to "elite" universities in the first place, they actually give themselves a much easier job than universities that accept students more broadly. Thus, university rankings are not useful to assess quality of education.

Comment: @gerrit I don’t disagree with you at all about state universities, their importance, the significance of the student population handled, and so on. I also wasn’t necessarily talking about US state universities, though—for most states, those aren’t second-tier or third-tier or so on, but really towards the low end. Which is a huge problem, and also is a fair point about how those take more challenging students and make it easier for “higher-tier” schools to do well. But my impression remains, for strong-but-not-top-tier students, the US has more strong options available.

Comment: Don't forget the United States is a wealthy nation with a huge population so it has a larger student base (and hence more top tier students) and more money to spend on education.

Comment: Just gonna leave this here: https://www.forbes.com/sites/robertfarrington/2018/12/12/student-loan-bubble-wont-burst/#4812673d6768

Comment: Because you cannot make money with elementary schools.

Answer (score 33):

The simple explanation is that virtually all K-12 schools are funded directly by governments (in other words they are politically-driven entities), while many colleges and universities are funded in no small part by tuition. Thus, if a public school system begins to fail, it may or may not get any reforms to stop it from failing in the future.

A simple Google search for "Harvard Tuition rates" gave me $50,420 for one year of tuition 2018-2019. [Actual list prices might be higher](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/04/05/it-costs-78200-to-go-to-harvardheres-what-students-actually-pay.html) and some students pay less than others based on financial assistance (the article quotes Harvard as saying students pay an average of $12,000). Harvard [also has a net worth of $38B](https://thebestschools.org/features/richest-universities-endowments-generosity-research/) and pays professors about $225,000. It also spends $1.1B on research annually (with a [fair amount of government-funded](https://harvardmagazine.com/2017/07/trump-to-research-drop-dead)). I'm willing to bet most of the [Ivy League schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_League) like Yale would clock in about the same. For the sake of argument, I'm going to run with those numbers for a minute.

State schools, by contrast, [spend about $10,000 per student](https://www.governing.com/gov-data/education-data/state-education-spending-per-pupil-data.html) (2016 numbers, with some as low as $7,000, and some as high as $22,000). That's not terribly surprising. States have to educate far more people and are obligated by law to do so. These schools are free to residents (in tuition, not taxation).

What's more important is that states have other things to do with that money beyond just funding education. Illinois, for instance, has a serious [teacher pension problem](https://www.illinoispolicy.org/nearly-40-of-education-spending-consumed-by-pension-costs/)

> In the [2020] school year, 36% of the money the state allocates to education will be diverted away from teachers and students to meet required pension payments for retirees.

In other words, $1 of every $3 for education is being spent on a non-education cost. And that's just pensions. We're not even talking the cost of buildings, buses, school lunches, etc. As such, Illinois [ranks 20th in graduations](https://www.dailyherald.com/article/20151215/news/312159866)

> New data from the U.S. Department of Education show that 86 percent of Illinois students graduate from high school. That's the 20th-highest graduation rate in the country [for 2015].

Furthermore, if I dislike the services that a university is providing, I can always change colleges. Thus it is in the interest of a university to ensure I can getting what I am paying for, lest I take my money elsewhere.

By contrast, if someone lives in a failing school district, they may not have any options at all to change schools. Worse is some districts are stuck in [The Lemon Dance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Hh6uHUx728), where underforming teachers are shoved between schools because they cannot be fired (New York City actually has [dedicated rooms](https://nypost.com/2016/01/17/city-pays-exiled-teachers-to-snooze-as-rubber-rooms-return/) for educators who cannot be in the classroom, but cannot be fired). This is why [charter schools](https://www.vox.com/2014/4/30/18076968/charter-schools) are contentious, because they are schools that can (and do) fail, but it offers some modicum of choice, even if that choice [involves an education lottery](https://www.theatlantic.com/education/archive/2014/03/what-applying-to-charter-schools-showed-me-about-inequality/284530/). Since that system is so hard to rely on [some people have become desperate enough to turn to fraud to get children better schooling](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/kelley-williams-bolar-schools_n_814857)

> Ohio mother of two Kelley Williams-Bolar was released from jail on Wednesday after serving nine days for falsifying records so that her two daughters could attend a better school.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107870/discussion-on-answer-by-machavity-why-does-the-united-states-have-some-of-the-be).

Answer (score 18):

To get down to the heart of it, In the USA, K-12 education is considered 'populist' while upper-level education is considered 'elite', which brings into play a whole range of social and political biases that affect funding and resource allocations.

K-12 education, ever since Dewey started pushing to universalize it at the end of the 19th century, was seen as an equalizer. Its goal was to ensure that even the poorest of children would receive basic knowledge and skills that would help them increase their standing in life, and make them better, more competent citizens. The arguments in favor were obvious. An agricultural worker of the 19th century sort could get by perfectly well without being able to read, write, or do arithmetic, because his livelihood did not require much knowledge of the world outside of the (complex) details of running a farm. But a twentieth century technological worker could not afford that same lack. Technical work required technical skills, which implied studying and learning; advancement in a technological world hinged on skills that could only be mastered with a basic level of education. Unless the USA was content to have a permanent underclass of illiterate workers, some kind of public education system was needed.

However, in the early twentieth century (and even now) this met with a lot of resistance. Those in the Jim Crow South objected, because they resented the idea that blacks might be allowed to advance with respect to whites. Those in the industrial Northeast resisted the idea that they should pay to educate the children of ignorant immigrant laborers, because (to the blue-blood mind) those children didn't need education beyond that needed to effectively work in a factory or a mine. And most of the country, honestly, held the bias that the education of children was women's work. 'Teacher' was perhaps the most respectable job a *woman* could reach for, but it was hardly considered a job at all by men, who viewed it as a natural extension of child-care.

By contrast, college and graduate work were and are viewed as vehicles for success, where 'superior' people could advance themselves into coveted positions in society. Thus, colleges and universities are willingly funded by the wealthy through tuition, donations, grants, funding of chairs and departments, etc. College is perceived to boost status in society for the elite who can manage to gain entry — whether through wealth or talent — and anything that boosts status, gains status.

Even today, public schooling is beset by people who complain that their tax dollars are being used to educate other people's children. I believe it was JD Salinger who (about ten years ago) sued New Hampshire because New Hampshire had passed a state tax that allocated revenue to public schools across the state, where Salinger thought his tax dollars should be dedicated only to his school district. Likewise, conservatives across the nation have pushed for voucher systems which pull tax dollars out of public schools to help certain people send their own children to private K-12 schools. The net effect of all these issues is to strip money from public institutions into more private and exclusive ones, extending the 'elitist' model of higher education down into the K-12 system.

Comment: There is a lot of truth to what you say wrt to local funding, as opposed to distributing the money equally.  Poor districts have poorly funded schools.  That is not however the entire story.  France distributes money equally, and in fact has merit pay for teachers working in challenging districts.  Nevertheless, the difference in outcomes between affluent and poor districts are massive there as well.  Thing is, for whatever reason it happens, once an area has a large proportion of kids who do not value education much (less than purely about $), it will be difficult to fix.

Comment: I have heard many of these claims before, and they all seem *plausible*, but it seems to me that a question like this deserves serious sourcing on claims. The only way anything is going to get better is for everyone to be very clear on what’s wrong with how things are now, so if this is what’s wrong, the answer needs to be rock-solid about demonstrating it.

Comment: +1. good historical elaboration in regards to class dynamics, and getting to the heart of the purpose of education in the view of governments. However, although not everything needs to be backed, some references would be nice. Also, more importantly, such views, such systems, and such issues are in other countries as well. So, how is it that your answer applies to other countries but they do not have the same end result as the US?

Comment: *'Teacher' was perhaps the most respectable job a woman could reach for, but it was hardly considered a job at all by men* — really?  I thought teachers were mostly male in the early 20th century.

Comment: @gerrit My understanding was that teaching shifted from men's work to women's work around the mid 19th Century due to both the belief that [women were more nurturing and benevolent](https://www.thewesterncarolinajournalist.com/2016/05/04/the-history-of-women-as-teachers/) and because [they were cheap and had less competition from other fields, which was important with the vast increase in teachers needed by public schools](https://www.pbs.org/onlyateacher/timeline.html).

Comment: While there is nothing technically wrong with this answer, and much good history, I think it could be stated in a more politically neutral form.  For instance, "Likewise, conservatives across the nation have pushed for voucher systems which pull tax dollars out of public schools to help certain people send their own children to private K-12 schools. The net effect of all these issues is to strip money from public institutions into more private and exclusive ones, extending the 'elitist' model of higher education down into the K-12 system." Is a pretty one-sided take on voucher systems.

Comment: @shellster: what do you think would be more neutral phrasing? Or at lest, what do you think is missing that might provide more balance?

Answer (score 13):

I would advise you to beware statistics!

Speaking as someone who works in the UK education sector, where we exhibit similar metrics to the US education system, when you start looking at world rankings you have to be aware that you are comparing societal educational values as much as educational outcomes.

OECD, who are the prime source for worldwide statistics base their PISA statistics on Mathematics, Science and Reading Comprehension, at age 15, because they are the only things that are important to a 15 year old, right?

The world rankings, as a result, ascribe a higher value to what I would call an Eastern-Style of education. The PISA rankings are topped by China, Singapore, Japan, etc and reflect the fact that these nations put a much higher value on a scientific education than many western nations do. In the UK, for example, it is a regular occurrence for 15 year old students to be spending 50+% of their time studying Arts & Humanities with the rest being a balance of Languages and the STEM subjects.

To summarise, I wouldn't pay to much attention to the "Average" rank of K-12 institutions, because it needs to be understood in the context of the relative breadth of the US curricula vs. other countries.

Comment: I will mention that as I was writing the question, I legitimately wrote out something along the lines of "I gauge there are/could be some bad statistics going on here. However, I suggest to make it simple." So, right you are

Comment: -1  if you're deficient in reading comprehension and basic math, you are going to struggle with a lot of important decision-making in the rest of your life.  You can dress that up as undue servitude towards "Asian-style learning by rote", but it's just pretty basic stuff, really.  The "breadth of the US curricula"? That's a rather big claim, considering the knowledge of the general US population wrt history, geography and sciences.  Welcome aboard, and sorry to disagree, but I do in this instance.

Comment: They aren't the only things that matter to a 15-year-old, but they are the foundation  on which every other subject rests.  You can't meaningfully study Arts and Humanities, or any other subject, without those basics.  And as per TedWrigley's answer, you can't even do most practical occupations (building, etc.) without a reasonable grasp of those basics, if you can't write a quote for a prospective client, estimate the material needed, or work out your profit.  The point isn't that students should be studying this at age 15, it's that they *should already know it* by age 15.

Comment: The argument here seems to be that while US students do in fact perform worse at science, math, and reading, they are better at subjects in the arts and humanities. Do you have any sources to support the notion that US students know more about art, history, or philosophy than other nations'?

Comment: You conveniently [left out Finland](https://finland.fi/life-society/finland-remains-among-top-nations-in-pisa-education-survey/).

Comment: @Graham Basics are not learned at 15. They are learned by 5th grade. Trigonometry is not basic, and its value is dubious for the majority of adults.

Comment: @paulj You might think that, but it's not quite true. Pythagoras in particular should be standard for anyone in construction to know how long a roof needs to be, just for one example. And that includes anyone doing anything as DIY too.

Comment: You are on to something, but I think you missed the mark.  Nations and states with large immigrant populations do poorly on these rankings, for reasons that hardly need explanation.  As Milton Friedman would suggest, if you want to compare Finland's educational system with America's, try comparing the former to the grandchildren of Finnish-American immigrants.  You'll surely find it to be close to a tie.

Comment: @pokep  yeah, I rather doubt that.  The US doesn't do near as well as Canada which has plenty of immigrants as well.  Different ethnic groups **do** have different educational outcomes, but assuming Caucasians (I am one) are necessarily on top is daft.  Plus, having experienced K-12 schooling in both the US and elsewhere (the Caribbean actually), I can tell you US K-12 expectations and standards are not that high.  I think the Finnish boys and girls would have a good at your claim and be rather sad at the outcome for their US cousins.

Comment: I am really rather surprised that my comment about the relative breadth of the U.S. curriculum found detractors. I thought it was common knowledge that China, for example, puts 9/15ths of its summative examination weightings into Language and Mathematics. Students in China then have the option to "round out" their studies by taking the remaining 6/15ths of their credits in either Physics, Chemistry and Biology or History, Geography and Politics. Most Chinese students take the Sciences route, which means they have no focus on Arts or Humanities during their secondary education, whatsoever.

Comment: You might think that the U.S. education doesn't have broad curricula, but Western curricula come nowhere near to the narrowness of focus of countries like China, Japan and Singapore. Intellectual elitism has always surrounded Mathematics and the Sciences, but I would ask those who believe that they have priority: should they come at the expense of subjects like Politics and History? Also, why are Biology and Chemistry considered more important than social sciences like Psychology and Sociology?

Comment: @Italian Philosophers   Look at US States that lack large immigrant and (sadly) urban black populations and you find results comparable to the top scoring nations worldwide.  Regarding Canada, for example - compare Iowa with Manitoba, or BC with Oregon and it's a pretty tight competition.  Add in NYC, Chicago, and LA, and the US falls behind.  But the same is true elsewhere.  Stockholm and Paris lag behind their hinterlands, too.   https://www.epi.org/publication/bringing-it-back-home-why-state-comparisons-are-more-useful-than-international-comparisons-for-improving-u-s-education-policy/

Comment: @pokep The highest performing US state still falls 6 to 9 ranks behind the China average (an average that includes low income / deprived Chinese people). How do you account for that if you don't accept that it is to do with a focussed curriculum? You should be comparing the top performing states with Beijing, where the education is exemplary, if you want to compare apples with apples.

Comment: @Graham The point that paulj was - I think - making was that in most countries the students have learned everything that they need from Mathematics to function as enfranchised citizens by the age of 12. Mathematics taught to 15 year olds, the kind that is being tested in the PISA scores, is quadratic equations, vector calculus, etc. To say that this level of Mathematics has more relevance to the average citizen than Politics is a bit of a stretch. If you want evidence of this, find out how many of your adult friends struggle to help their children with 15 year old Mathematics homework :)

Comment: @Nuclear Wang I think you highlighted my point perfectly. Thanks for that! The PISA rankings exclude any comparative data for the Humanities and Arts. You know why they do that? Because you can't compare a data set with a null data set. Many Eastern nations don't have statistics on academic outcomes for "History of Art", "Music Theory", "Philosophy", "Psychology", etc because they don't even HAVE those subjects in their curricula.

Comment: @MarkusOreallyus Both you and he are making incorrect assumptions though. I suggest you go to the PISA website and take their example tests. The PISA tests for a 15-year-old ask for nothing more complex than working out averages, or working out the length of time something will take and using that to work out when to start in order to finish at a set time. The PISA tests are not the same as what might be taught at that age.

Comment: @MarkusOreallyus And further to your last post, most schools everywhere don't have those subjects, nor are they necessary for an enfranchised population able to make competent decisions. The current situation with COVID-19 clearly demonstrates that a large minority of the US population are not capable of using basic facts to make competent decisions. And if the people voting are not able to make competent decisions, then democracy as a concept becomes impossible.

Comment: @Graham So you seem to be acknowledging that the PISA tests are valid, yet they undermine your point about trigonometry, do they not? If the PISA tests are, in fact, a good indicator of the level of required competence for a functioning citizen then you don't actually need to be conversant in radians, sine, cosine, etc, which is the point paulj made.

Comment: @Graham "nor are they necessary for an enfranchised population" Are you seriously suggesting that a narrower educational focus, with fewer subjects, is likely to make people BETTER educated?

Comment: @MarkusOreallyus He said that the PISA tests were not relevant because they were testing at the level of sine, cosine, etc.. That is untrue, which makes his point, well, pointless. Whether your education system continues to teach you sine and cosine is irrelevant, because the PISA tests cover stuff you should have learnt years before. My 9-year-old son can do all the examples I pulled up from the PISA tests, and he's fairly bright but he's not top of the class in maths.

Comment: @MarkusOreallyus How do you associate "better educated" with "being an enfranchised population able to make rational choices"? I'm saying there's a minimum standard of education necessary, and the PISA tests fit it fairly well (as they're designed to). And all that, you should have learnt by at least 12-13 in any Western school system. That has nothing to do with the breadth of subjects you learn later. But if you don't have those absolute basics, you are fundamentally unable to learn any of those higher subjects, and it also blocks you from working effectively when you complete school.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107597/discussion-between-markusoreallyus-and-graham).

Answer (score 8):

Funding issues have already been mentioned, but there are other major dynamics at play here, too: especially rigor and the standards used to measure success... and the stratification that those factors lead to.

### Performance Metrics

Performance metrics for public primary and secondary schools in the U.S. are based largely on how many of their students graduate. They are constantly under heavy pressure to make sure the slowest students in their classes can keep up and the makeup of the classes are often more or less random relative to the population assigned to attend that school, with often little-to-no stratification based on ability, especially in the primary grades. This means that the entire classes are often, if not usually, slowed down to paces where the slowest students can at least come close to keeping up. Meanwhile, the students most proficient in a given field will be bored and mostly unchallenged (yeah... personal experience there.)

Tertiary education - especially at universities - is thought of entirely differently. Their standards for success are more along the lines of academic prestige (especially with regards to their research production,) how easily their graduates can find jobs in their desired fields, how much those jobs pay, etc. This leads to a *dramatic* difference in focus.

### Selection of Students

One of the most dramatic differences is that colleges can *select which students they admit* and students can *select the colleges to which they apply*. This leads to far more stratification in courses by ability level, both from student self-selection and selection from among the applicants by the colleges. This, in turn, allows the courses - especially at higher-ranking universities - to have much faster paces where even the most proficient students can be constantly challenged.

Another of the most dramatic differences is that college instructors/professors are also under *far* less pressure to make sure everyone passes than their primary and secondary counterparts. On the contrary, they're under more pressure to make sure that their courses are sufficiently rigorous that the students who pass them will be prepared for jobs and/or research in those fields. This dramatic difference in focus and rigor often comes as quite a shock to first-year students and, as a result, pass rates, especially in the first year, are *far* lower than in primary and secondary education. At the more technically-focused university I attended (known mostly for its engineering school,) it was not uncommon for first-year courses like Calculus, physics, chemistry, and introductory computer programming/software design courses to have pass rates around *half*. And that's *after* the aforementioned self-selection of the university by students and students by the university. These courses are often known as "weed-out" courses due to their propensity to result in a large number of change-of-major forms being filled out by first-year students and even more first-year students who drop out or are placed on academic suspension. They are also jokingly known among both upper-division students and faculty to be the courses that freed up parking spaces in the university's parking lots...

These factors then feed even further into stratification based on abilities and motivation. By the time you get to upper-division classes (i.e. third- and fourth-year undergraduate classes,) only the students who have actually survived the first-year and second-year courses remain, which then allows the courses to be *far* more focused and academically rigorous than anything you would find in a public secondary school.

Then along comes graduate school, adding yet another layer of stratification by ability and motivation, again by means of self-selection on the part of both the students and the university graduate programs' admissions processes. It's at this level where much of the "academic prestige" factor comes in for universities, as this is where the vast majority of the research is done. [According to the U.S. Census](https://www.census.gov/library/stories/2019/02/number-of-people-with-masters-and-phd-degrees-double-since-2000.html), 13.1% of Americans aged 25 and over currently possess at least a Master's degree. If you remove the [41% of those](https://nces.ed.gov/programs/coe/pdf/coe_ctb.pdf) in the mostly non-research-based [MBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Business_Administration) and [M.Ed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Education) programs, you're down to a highly-self-selected 7-8% of the population. By contrast, [over 90%](https://www.census.gov/newsroom/press-releases/2017/educational-attainment-2017.html) (and [93% of those aged 25-30](https://www.census.gov/library/visualizations/2017/comm/education-bachelors.html)) have at least a high-school level education.

### Selection of Faculty

While I think the above accounts for the vast majority of the difference, it's also important to point out the differences on the faculty side of the equation in universities, as well. Whereas the average primary or secondary teacher will have a Bachelor's and maybe M.Ed., virtually all university professors will have a Ph.D. or equivalent terminal degree. And that terminal degree will typically be in the specific field-of-study that they're teaching and/or researching, rather than a more general education degree as is typical for primary and secondary education teachers. The selection process for university faculty is also far more rigorous than for primary and secondary education, with the university faculty selection committees typically seeking out literally world-class experts in the specific fields that they will be teaching and researching. And, going back to the beginning of the answer, the standards of success that the faculty are measured by in universities are mostly their academic qualifications and research production, not so much how much they go out of their way to make sure every student who enters their door passes and standardized test scores like in primary and secondary schools.

Comment: maybe I am putting words in the OPs mouth, but it seems this question is about the success of US universities wrt world rankings vs the relative failure of US K-12 wrt world rankings.  not so much why universities *are better* than K-12.  Most of these points, aside from #1, apply equally to most other countries.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica So, I guess the answer to that then is basically, "Because the factors that are pulling down primary and secondary schools don't apply to universities" for the reasons mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a huge misconception, US K12 education is actually absolutely top-notch, but there are significant disparities among various ethnic groups that muddle the picture.

There is an organisation called [PISA](https://www.oecd.org/pisa/), that runs massive tests of high school students every 3 years(It's what the question's Pew article was referring to. PISA also provides demographic information in their data and here are the results for the US in 2018, in comparison to every other country in the test dataset, ranked from best to worst:

```
| Education system          | Mean  | Reading   | Math  | Science   |
|-------------------------  |------ |---------  |------ |---------  |
| B-S-J-Z (China)           | 579   | 555       | 591   | 590       |
| Singapore                 | 556   | 549       | 569   | 551       |
```

```
| Asian Americans           | 549   | 556       | 539   | 551       |
```

```
| Macau (China)             | 542   | 525       | 558   | 544       |
| Hong Kong (China)         | 531   | 524       | 551   | 517       |
| Estonia                   | 525   | 523       | 523   | 530       |
```

```
| European Americans        | 521   | 531       | 503   | 529       |
```

```
| Japan                     | 520   | 504       | 527   | 529       |
| Korea, Republic of        | 520   | 514       | 526   | 519       |
| Canada                    | 517   | 520       | 512   | 518       |
| Chinese Taipei            | 517   | 503       | 531   | 516       |
| Finland                   | 516   | 520       | 507   | 522       |
| Poland                    | 513   | 512       | 516   | 511       |
| Ireland                   | 505   | 518       | 500   | 496       |
| Slovenia                  | 504   | 495       | 509   | 507       |
| United Kingdom            | 504   | 504       | 502   | 505       |
| New Zealand               | 503   | 506       | 494   | 508       |
| Sweden                    | 502   | 506       | 502   | 499       |
| Netherlands               | 502   | 485       | 519   | 503       |
| Denmark                   | 501   | 501       | 509   | 493       |
| Germany                   | 500   | 498       | 500   | 503       |
| Belgium                   | 500   | 493       | 508   | 499       |
| Australia                 | 499   | 503       | 491   | 503       |
| Switzerland               | 498   | 484       | 515   | 495       |
| Norway                    | 497   | 499       | 501   | 490       |
| Czech Republic            | 495   | 490       | 499   | 497       |
| United States             | 495   | 505       | 478   | 502       |
| France                    | 494   | 493       | 495   | 493       |
```

```
| Multi-racial Americans    | 492   | 501       | 474   | 502       |
```

```
| Portugal                  | 492   | 492       | 492   | 492       |
| Austria                   | 491   | 484       | 499   | 490       |
| OECD average              | 488   | 487       | 489   | 489       |
| Latvia                    | 487   | 479       | 496   | 487       |
| Spain                     | NA    | NA        | 481   | 483       |
| Russian Federation        | 482   | 479       | 488   | 478       |
| Iceland                   | 481   | 474       | 495   | 475       |
| Lithuania                 | 480   | 476       | 481   | 482       |
| Hungary                   | 479   | 476       | 481   | 481       |
| Italy                     | 477   | 476       | 487   | 468       |
| Luxembourg                | 477   | 470       | 483   | 477       |
| Belarus                   | 472   | 474       | 472   | 471       |
| Croatia                   | 472   | 479       | 464   | 472       |
```

```
| Hispanic Americans        | 470   | 481       | 452   | 478       |
```

```
| Slovak Republic           | 469   | 458       | 486   | 464       |
| Israel                    | 465   | 470       | 463   | 462       |
| Turkey                    | 463   | 466       | 454   | 468       |
| Ukraine                   | 463   | 466       | 453   | 469       |
| Malta                     | 459   | 448       | 472   | 457       |
| Greece                    | 453   | 457       | 451   | 452       |
| Serbia                    | 442   | 439       | 448   | 440       |
| Cyprus                    | 438   | 424       | 451   | 439       |
| Chile                     | 438   | 452       | 417   | 444       |
```

```
| African Americans         | 436   | 448       | 419   | 440       |
```

```
| United Arab Emirates      | 434   | 432       | 435   | 434       |
| Malaysia                  | 431   | 415       | 440   | 438       |
| Romania                   | 428   | 428       | 430   | 426       |
| Bulgaria                  | 427   | 420       | 436   | 424       |
| Moldova, Republic of      | 424   | 424       | 421   | 428       |
| Uruguay                   | 424   | 427       | 418   | 426       |
| Brunei Darussalam         | 423   | 408       | 430   | 431       |
| Montenegro, Republic of   | 422   | 421       | 430   | 415       |
| Albania                   | 420   | 405       | 437   | 417       |
| Jordan                    | 416   | 419       | 400   | 429       |
| Mexico                    | 416   | 420       | 409   | 419       |
| Costa Rica                | 415   | 426       | 402   | 416       |
| Qatar                     | 413   | 407       | 414   | 419       |
| Thailand                  | 413   | 393       | 419   | 426       |
| Colombia                  | 405   | 412       | 391   | 413       |
| Bosnia and Herzegovina    | 402   | 403       | 406   | 398       |
| Kazakhstan                | 402   | 387       | 423   | 397       |
| Baku (Azerbaijan)         | 402   | 389       | 420   | 398       |
| Peru                      | 402   | 401       | 400   | 404       |
| Brazil                    | 400   | 413       | 384   | 404       |
| North Macedonia           | 400   | 393       | 394   | 413       |
| Argentina                 | 395   | 402       | 379   | 404       |
| Georgia                   | 387   | 380       | 398   | 383       |
| Saudi Arabia              | 386   | 399       | 373   | 386       |
| Indonesia                 | 382   | 371       | 379   | 396       |
| Lebanon                   | 377   | 353       | 393   | 384       |
| Morocco                   | 368   | 359       | 368   | 377       |
| Panama                    | 365   | 377       | 353   | 365       |
| Kosovo                    | 361   | 353       | 366   | 365       |
| Philippines               | 350   | 340       | 353   | 357       |
| Dominican Republic        | 334   | 342       | 325   | 336       |
```

As you can see, in terms of actually educating it's students, the US educates:

- It's Asian origin students better than any other Asian country other than Singapore and the BSJZ(Beijing, Shanghai, Jiangsu and Zhejiang) region of China.
- It's European origin students better than any European country other than Estonia.
- It's Hispanic origin students **way** better than any Latin American country.

The only African country that participated in PISA is Morocco, but since it's near the top of African countries in HDI, it's safe to say that the other African countries are at least as bad as, or much worse at educating their students than the US is at educating African Americans.

I'm not speculating upon the reasons for the group differences, because it's a white hot, radioactive potato and not relevant to the question, I'm just pointing out that the US is actually doing great at educating whichever children it has.

This is actually a classic example of [Simpson's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox), but mentioning group differences is understandably avoided, so every time PISA results come out, there is the same set of predictable articles lamenting the US K12 education system and they'll be the same in 2021, when the next round of PISA tests takes place.

Comment: 1) You should either compare entire countries or split the results by demographic groups in every country. Most countries have significant ethnic minorities, and minority students often perform significantly worse than majority students. 2) You should look at the full distributions. Ranking the countries by the mean score (or by any other single statistic) yields biased results.

Comment: I would guess, at least in the case of Asian-Americans, that there's a lot of selection bias going on here. A large percentage of Asian immigrants to the U.S. are highly-educated tech workers or university professors, so it's not especially surprising that their children would outperform the average either in the U.S. or in their home country. The comparison of European-descent Americans vs. Europeans is more interesting, though. While phrases like "lowest common denominator" are much more indicative of my U.S. public K-12 experience than "top notch," this is interesting data, so +1.

Comment: @reirab The comparison between European Americans and Europeans is also problematic. Europe is not 100% European, and the language and cultural barriers immigrants face in Europe are often much worse than in America.

Comment: @JouniSirén,European Americans out-performed European countries like Poland, czechia,slovakia, hungary, etc. that are so close to mono-ethnic and also beat out Finland, which still has a relatively small immigrant population and is regularly held up as the gold standard of K12 education, so it's still a valid comparison.

Comment: @reirab, you are overestimating how many Asian American kids are the children of high tech workers, Asian American is a very broad category, that includes everyone from Hmong Refugees and Vietnamese boat people, to Phillipinos to Indians with masters degrees working in Silicone valley:https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2017/09/08/key-facts-about-asian-americans/ However,  if they can  be generalized, they generally come from cultures that value education and even for that heterogenous category, the American K12 system is good enough to blow all but the richest Asian regions out of the water

Comment: @Eugene In Finland, the average score was 522 among the native population, 434 among first-generation immigrants, and 455 among second-generation immigrants. The scores have come down by 10-30 points in the past 10 years, so the current results should not be considered particularly good.

Comment: @JouniSirén, ah, didn't notice that the Finland data had that breakdown. I guess that Finland has it's own version of the US group outcome discrepancy now. Have people started bemoaning the state of Finnish education yet? However, even in that case, 521 for European Americans vs 522 for native Finns and 525 for the top of the European heap Estonians, still shows off the American K12 system very favorably.

Comment: @Eugene The consensus in Finland is that the decline is mostly cultural. Some groups no longer value education as much as they used to. Anyway, when we compare school systems, we should look at the entire score distributions. In addition to relatively high average PISA scores, the Finnish system also has very low variation between schools. There are no bad schools in Finland.

Comment: @Eugene I'm aware of the breadth of the Asian-American category, but a very large percentage of _recent_ immigrants from Asia - the ones whose children would be in schools over the last 10-20 years - are indeed highly educated. Even with regard to the Philippines, where poverty on a level not really seen anywhere in America is the norm, the average Filipino-American earns more than the average European-descent American. The selection bias is quite real. Granted, the data likely looked quite different in the 70s/early 80s when a lot of the immigrants from Asia were fleeing wars and communism.

Comment: @Eugene In 2016, the _median_ Filipino-American household had an income of $88,745, [according to the U.S. Census](https://archive.vn/20200213040005/https://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/16_1YR/S0201//popgroup~-04), for example. That's much higher than the median even for European-descent Americans. Some 37% of those were in education or healthcare.

Comment: @reirab (1)Are you implying that only recent immigrants have Asian American children in school? The descendants of the earlier waves of immigration are still mostly Asian for the purposes of PISA(with some multi-racial). If you look at the breadth of Asian immigration over the last 100+ years, it is not "elite". My point was that the US K12 will educate you to the best world standards if you want to be educated(or have an Asian mother ready to thrash you if you get a B in math. European Americans have a more relaxed attitude towards education, but still on par with the top European countries.

Comment: @reirab (2) From talking to the very few African American co-workers in my field, studying hard, or being a computer nerd will get your ass kicked by your peers in the hood, for "acting white" and not "keeping it real". It's for this reason that I've met more Nigerian co-workers than actual "native" African Americans(and Nigerians and their 1-st gen kids do really well in the US, because the ones who made it, are here because of education). P.S. I didn't say Filipino Americans were poor, I placed them midway on the spectrum, where the top end was "Indians with masters degrees in The Valley"

Comment: @Eugene Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that you said Filipino-Americans were poor. I was just pointing that out that statistic to highlight the selection bias involved in the cohort of Asians who immigrate to the U.S. Compared to the U.S., the Philippines is extremely poor, yet Filipino-Americans have significantly higher median incomes than most other American demographics, highlighting that the (rather extreme) selection bias toward the wealthier and more educated for immigration to the U.S. Agreed about the role of parenting in determining educational outcomes.